# How to get release configuration back

Tags: xcode

I deleted all the Release configurations in Xcode and now have only Debug. Is there a way to create another release configuration? I am looking to get Xcode to look like the image below.

[image]

Comment: 3 pixels below your screenshot should be a + and -. Tap the + and add back the release configuration.

Comment: @rmaddy the + button only allows you to duplicate an existing configuration. If you don't have any release configs, there's no option to add one from the + list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to directly recreate the lost Release configuration.

You have two painful options:

1. Create a new project and copy all of your files from your existing project to your new project.
2. Copy the Debug configuration in the project with the missing Release configuration. Name the copy to Release. Then update all of the Build Settings for the new Release configuration.

Option 2 can be done by clicking the + icon just below the screenshot shown in the question. Then select "Duplicate "Debug" Configuration". Give the new configuration the name of "Release". The trick now is knowing what all of the release settings need to be. Create a new dummy project using the same template you used for your actual project. Then select the project and then the Build Settings tab. Choose the "Customized" and "Levels" options. Now scan down the list to see where it shows different values for Debug and Release. Make those same changes in your actual project.

As you can see in the picture below, the **Build Active Architecture Only**, **Debug Information Format**, **Enable Testability**, etc. settings are different between Debug and Release.

[image]